# Providing "Totals" for custom SQL queries on a regular basis

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like some advice on how to best go about what I'm trying to achieve.

I'd like to provide a user with a screen that will display one or more "icon" (per say) and display a total next to it (bit like the iPhone does). Don't worry about the UI, the question is not about that, it is more about how to handle the back-end.

Let's say for argument sake, I want to provide the following:

- Total number of unread records
- Total number of waiting for approval
- Total number of pre-approved
- Total number of approved
- etc...

I suppose, the easiest way to descrive the above would be "MS Outlook". Whenever emails arrive to your inbox, you can see the number of unread email being updated immediately. I know it's local, so it's a bit different, but now imagine having the same principle but for the queries above.

This could vary from user to user and while dynamic stored procedures are not ideal, I don't think I could write one sp for each scenario, but again, that's not the issue heree.

Now the recommendation part:

1. Should I be creating a timer that polls the database every minute (for example?) and run-all my relevant sql queries which will then provide me with the relevant information.
2. Is there a way to do this in real time without having a "polling" mechanism i.e. Whenever a query changes, it updates the total/count and then pushes out the count of the query to the relevant client(s)?
3. Should I have some sort of table storing these "totals" for each query and handle the updating of these immediately based on triggers in SQL and then when queried by a user, it would only read the "total" rather than trying to calculate them?

The problem with triggers is that these would have to be defined individually and I'm really tring to keep this as generic as possible... Again, I'm not 100% clear on how to handle this to be honest, so let me know what you think is best or how you would go about it.

Ideally when a specific query is created, I'd like to provide to choices. 1) General (where anyone can use this) and b) Specific where the "username" would be used as part of the query and the count returned would only be applied for that user but that's another issue.

The important part is really the notification part. While the polling is easy, I'm not sure I like it.

Imagine if I had 50 queries to be execute and I've got 500 users (unlikely, but still!) looking at the screen with these icons. 500 users would poll the database every minute and 50 queries would also be executed, this could potentially be 25000 queries per miuntes... Just doesn't sound right.

As mentioned, ideally, a) I'd love to have the data changes in real-time rather than having to wait a minute to be notified of a new "count" and b) I want to reduce the amount of queries to a minimum. Maybe I won't have a choice.

The idea behind this, is that they will have a small icon for each of these queries, and a little number will be displayed indicating how many records apply to the relevant query. When they click on this, it will bring them the relevant result data rather than the actual count and then can deal with it accordingly.

I don't know if I've explained this correctly, but if unclear, please ask, but hopefully I have and I'll be able to get some feedback on this.

Looking forward to your feeback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the ideal solution but maybe a decent 1.

The following are the assumptions I have taken

1. Considering that your front end is a web application i.e. asp.net
2. The data which needs to be fetched on a regular basis is not hugh
3. The data which needs to be fetched does not change very frequently

If I were in this situation then I would have gone with the following approach

1. Implemented SQL Caching using SQLCacheDependency class. This class will fetch the data from the database and store in the cache of the application. The cache will get invalidated whenever the data in the table on which the dependency is created changes thus fetching the new data and again creating the cache. And you just need to get the data from the cache rest everything (polling the database, etc) is done by asp.net itself. [Here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1382-how-to-implement-sql-caching-in-aspnet-poll-based-sql-cache-dependency-.aspx) is a link which describes the steps to implement SQL Caching and believe me it is not that difficult to implement.
2. Use AJAX to update the counts on the UI so that the User does not feel the pinch of PostBack.

Comment: I'll certainly look into this, but a) it would be required for both web (silverlight) and windows (winform). While I don't believe the number of queries will be huge i.e. 10, max 20 (really up to customer to be honest!).. It still fairly high having to run 10/20 queries if all users would be in this module which would display the total number of records "matching" a specific query. As explained below this number would basically be a "count" of our generic search query. Could our "server" do the constant query, cache it and then when a client requests it, read it from the cache instead?

Answer (score 0):

What about "[Improving Performance with SQL Server 2008 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)"?

> "This is often particularly effective for aggregate views in decision
>   support or data warehouse environments"

Comment: Aren't views meant to be very static? At the moment we have a generic "Search function" which can be used by all our customers which all have different fields defined and while dynamic sp are not ideal, this is the only way we could handle all scenarios. What we want to achieve is create numerous "notification" icons which will display how many records match a specific search and display the total on an icon, so would a view still fall into that category? We definitely cannot have a view for every "notification" count icon scenario as this once again would greatly vary for all customers.

Comment: You can create a view with this structure: userID, count1, count2, count3, ..., count_n. With a create view user_counts as select userId, count( distinct ... ). Then map this view with an entity UserCounts and use the entity to display user Icons. For improve performance you can create a view for each icon but never a view for each user.

Comment: I'll have to look into this further. It would definitely be a view for each icon rather than each user, but while not ideal, I'd still like to re-use our dynamic stored procedure which is responsible for our search but instead will return a count but I'm not sure about having a view with a dynamic sp in it?? Doesn't seem to make much sense. The only +, I guess is that the values in it would be hard-coded when calling the dynamic sp but it would only return the count rather than the actual result. I don't really know if it is a plus to be honest... as I said I'll have to look into it further.